# How can i setup raid 0 with 2xhdd and ssd for cache in ubuntu 20.10

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, performance, 20.10

I am using nvme pcie4 for ubuntu booting

i would like to use my 2 hard drives for raid 0 with an ssd for cache

2x2tb hard drives

1x2500gb ssd

how should i proceed?

i am looking for maximum performance